# Set default value in minutes for a smalldatetime column in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am unable to set a default value of 5 min to a `smalldatetime` column in SQL Server 2008.
Any help is appreciated

thanks,
Green

Comment: Why don't you use [`TIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243(v=sql.105).aspx) datatype for your `TimeSpan`?

Comment: and how do i set default value of say 5 min to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #t(col TIME DEFAULT '00:05')
INSERT #t VALUES (DEFAULT)
SELECT  *
FROM    #t
```

As Tim suggested better thing would be to use `TIME` data type.